# Is a reference write always atomic?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, size

According to this question: [How big is an object reference in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net) , .Net references are 32bit on x86 and 64bit on x64. When a 64bit reference is written is it done atomically or as 2 separate 32bit writes, as is done with a long?

Comment: @Steve, I'm confused why you thought it was dupe of the question already linked and summarized in this question.  The second question, however, gives a definitive answer, confirmed correct by a user who was then a member of the C# compiler team.

Comment: @BenVoigt The question was originally a 2 parter. The first part was addressed by the duplicate link, so I reworded the question.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.