# Tagged pointer for .NET (C#) object reference

Tags: c#, .net

I learned that [an object reference of .NET (C#) is just a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net).

My questions are:

- Is the address of the object [aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) depending on the CPU architecture and/or the object's size?
- If the above is yes, can I make efficient use of a few of least significant bits of the object reference as a [tagged pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# (a language). It is *only* a pointer to the implementation, if it chooses to use such.

Comment: The compile optimizes the code depending on the settings like CPU and X86 for speed and memory.  The alignment can be force by inserting compile directives, but adding these probably will make the optimizer less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a .NET reference is not a pointer. Of course, in most implementations running on modern hardware, it may use a pointer as part of the implementation. This simply has to do with the limits of modern hardware - no CPU supports references at this time, as far as I'm aware. x86 definitely doesn't :)

You shouldn't think about things like this in .NET at all - you're not getting any of this as part of the contract you have with .NET. You only care about things like these when dealing with native interop, or when you really have to optimize some tiny thing. And the question is meaningless anyway, since you can't manipulate references in the way you'd want, regardless of whether they're internally implemented as pointers or not. Even if you could, the underlying pointer (if any) may change at any time at the discretion of the memory manager - it can be moved between heaps or within heaps at any time.

.NET also has actual pointers. If you really feel the need to deal with such constructs, you can. Of course, in that case, you most likely want to use C++ instead of C# anyway, regardless of whether you go full-native, C++/CLI or mixed-module.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question:

> Is the address of the object aligned depending on the CPU architecture
>   and/or the object's size?

Memory reference size of an object do depends on CPU architecture. So to say, if it's 32-bits system that means it can cover a virtual memory space of 2^32 bits (or 2^64 bits in case of 64 bits architecture) and thus the memory reference/address size will occupy 32 bits/4 bytes (or) 64 bits/8 bytes accordingly.