# Memory performance IList<T> vs List<T> property

Tags: c#

I'm writing a class where I have a collection of objects of class A and I'm writing a function similar to `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey,TValue)`

It looks pretty similar to this:

```
public class MyCollection
{
   public List<A> Collection {get; set;} = new List<A>();

   public bool TryGetPropertyAByPropertyB(string pPropertyB, out string pPropertyA)
   { … }
}
```

I'm just wondering if I replaced List for IList, would it be more efficient (talking about memory)?

```
public class MyCollection
{
   public IList<A> Collection {get; set;} = new List<A>();

   public bool TryGetPropertyAByPropertyB(string pPropertyB, out string pPropertyA)
   { … }
}
```

Comment: No - it's going to be the same `List` instance whether you call it  a`List<T>` or an `IList<T>`

Comment: `IList` is only an interface and doesn't have any implementation.  You're comparing apples and volkswagons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/listt-or-ilistt)

Comment: There *may* be a small memory difference if there is code which currently uses a method on `List<T>`, and there's no equivalent method on `IList<T>` (such as `BinrarySearch`), and this code then needs to buffer the elements in the list. But there's no difference in the memory usage of the actual `List<T>`.

Comment: No. DI will just make any IList a List at runtime

Comment: Unless you change the actual data structure (e.g. changing `new List<A>();` to some other custom data structure), there will be no difference.

Comment: You need to go all the way back and ask yourself 1) if you need to care about memory and 2) if you do, how you plan to identify actual problems. Picking at random bits of code and wondering if option A or option B might use more memory is a counterproductive waste of time -- even if the answer is "yes", you still have no idea of the actual impact.

Comment: perhaps interestingly (who knows), there *will* be a difference if you `foreach` over the data, due to how `foreach` is implemented (duck-typing, custom iterators, etc); but most of the time: no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a reference of type `List<T>` and a reference of type `IList<T>` are of the exact same size, [usually 32 or 64 bits depending on the target platform's architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net).

In both cases you're creating a `new List<T>`. The type of the actual object that lives on the heap does not depend on the type of the reference to which it is assigned. You can say `object x = new List<T>()` and it's still a fully functional instance of a `List<T>` created "somewhere", even though you're only holding a reference of type `object`.

It'd be interesting to hear how you got the idea that it *could* make a difference? Maybe you need to read up on the basics of C#/.NET, starting with reference and value types?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: It said that *The reference itself is basically a pointer. 32 bits on a 32 bit OS, 64 bits on a 64 bit OS. The size of the object that's referenced is more complicated.* I agree that the reference is the same but doing the change to IList, couldn't the size of the object be more lightweight?

Comment: Thank you, it sounds reasonable, although, if you do object x = new List<T>() you lose some features of List, couldn't this loss be associated to memory release?

Comment: @CarlosPozos You can always recast it back to a `List<T>` with `(List<T>) x`.

Comment: @CarlosPozos Referring to a `List<T>` as an object or as an interface has *no effect* on the runtime type, or the runtime type's memory usage.  It's still a list.  The only difference it would make memory-wise is the reference itself.