# What size is the pointer to the class?

Tags: c#

```cs
 public class PersonClass
 {
        public string Name;
        public string Name1;
        public string Name2;
        public byte Age;
        public byte Age1;
        public byte Age2;
 }
```

I want know how much memory will be allocated on the stack if I will make such as assignment:

```cs
var newPerson = new PersonClass() // <- allocated new PersonsClass object
var pointer = newPerson // <- how match bytes will be allocated on stack?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net

Comment: What you have there is a reference type, not a value type, so far less is on the stack than you might think. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605621/4137916) touches on the size aspect beyond the reference, but see also Eric Lippert's ["the stack is an implementation detail"](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one). There are many misconceptions programmers working in managed languages have when they port conventional wisdom from C-like languages, so the simple stack/heap dual model very often does not apply.